# Hand-pressed metal stamping - fishing spinner blades

Tags: machining, metals, manufacturing-engineering

I want to stamp my own fishing spinner blades.

They look like this:

http://lurepartsonline.com/Online-Store/Colorado-Blades/Premium-Finish-Colorado-Blades.html

Specs are usually 1mm thick, 3x2" oval curved oval. Ideally, I would want to be able to adjust the size and shape, or apply grooves/patterns to the blade. I assume I can buy bulk sheet metal from a hardware store.

I'm thinking I could possibly get 3d-printed casts for different designs, or possibly prebuilt shapes?

I'm mostly a programmer, not a mechanic, so I'm just looking for a general idea of what is possible.

Is this feasible, and how much should I expect to pay in machinery?

I've seen some hydraulic presses go for under $1000, but it's a private hobby of mine and I could probably pay well over that if necessary.

I want to stress that this is an at home hobby and I don't want to rent machinery or order custom designs from a factory.

I realize cutting the metal won't necessarily give a perfect shine, so any addition points on finishing/painting would be appreciated.

This is a video of how these things are generally produced commercially:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjovDNw1GcY

Comment: Nothing is impossible and if you're willing to settle for much lower quality, you could get there,but based on your question I think there's a whole lot more explaining to get you to a good answer than anyone is likely to provide here. I would recommend doing some research on similar home stamping operations, sketch the kind of setup you want to do, and coming back with any specific questions when you're ready to pick components and manufacture your dies.

Comment: To echo Ethan48's comment - you have a lot of big questions rolled up into a single question.  With that much material to cover, you won't get quality answers beyond what some simple web researching will provide you.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on something similar myself recently, albeit in somewhat thinner material.

For 1 mm thick metal stock it is well worth considering getting your flat  blanks laser or water jet cut. In most countries there are plenty of local suppliers who will be happy to do this for you based on either a hand drawing or a vector graphics file and it isn't usually very expensive especially as they may be able to get volume discounts on materials. This is quite likely to be more economical than setting up to stamp them yourself from sheet material.

In terms of forming you may well be able to get away with a fairly cheap manual press, something like a fly or arbour press as it looks like the dishing is fairly shallow. as you say you will need dies to do this and here you have  a few options. 3-D printing may not be an ideal option as most consumer processes use plastics which aren't remotely up to the sort of forces involved.

For the sort of fairly flat shapes you have linked to it may be practical to grind your own dies from tool steel blanks with  either a hand held die grinder, pendant drill or a milling machine again you also have the option to get them CNC machined by a third party as long as you can produce a 3-D model of the form you want.

Of course doing it yourself gives you more flexibility to fine tune the forms as you go along.

You might also consider casting the dies, setting up a home bronze foundry is certainly within the realms of an ambitious hobbyist if you are prepared to invest a moderate amount of time and money and forging them in steel is also realistic option.

For thin metal is is also perfectly viable to cold work them to shape on open dies or using a pitch bowl. This is more labour and skill intensive per unit but don't require a large investment in equipment

For finishing a polishing lathe can be used for manual finishing and de-burring, I would think you would be looking at textile mops, fleece (scotchbrite) wheels and possibly unitised wheels.

A barrel polisher is also worth looking at for more efficient bulk finishing and polishing of small items.

If you want to work with aluminium a home anodising setup is also worth considering. I don;t know if photo etching would be useful here but that is also a reasonable hobby technology for fine metalworking.